# How Objectify store Object of same name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

When an app will store two kinds of Entity:

```
com.mycompany.kind.Model
```

and

```
com.mycompany.otherkind.Model
```

How will this be stored in the Datastore collection, in the same kind "Model"? Or not?

Comment: You should check the structure of the key, a datastore Key is made up of (Kind, ID) with possibly multiple ancestors.  If Kind is derived just from Model name, then you could have two different types of the same Kind stored. This can happen in the python environment if someone defines the model in two different modules - of course they shouldn't. So it will depend on how "Kind" is generated in Objectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the @Entity annotation to deconflict your kind names:

```
@Entity
public class Model { ... }


@Entity(name="OtherModel")
public class Model { ... }
```

This can be dangerous for obvious reasons. I would not recommend it.